# Clipboard.SetContent() The remote procedure call failed

Tags: uwp, clipboard, procedure

In my UWP Application When I am trying to set the content in the `Clipboard` I am getting the below exception.

Targeted SDK version: Windows 10 SDK, version 1903

> System.Exception: The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800706BE)    at
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.SetContent(DataPackage
>   content)

```
public static void CopyTextToClipboard(string textToCopy)
{          
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToCopy))
    {
       var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
       dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
       dataPackage.SetText(textToCopy.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty));
       Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Clipboard.SetContent` must be called from the UI thread. In case you are executing this code from a different thread, you must wrap the `Clipboard` call inside a `Dispatcher.RunAsync`:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage));
```

Also, note this means `Clipboard` cannot be used from a background service as well (this has no associated UI thread).

Comment: Hi
We have tried the above code.The issue is with Windows OS version 1809 & 1903. Below 1809 there is no issue

Comment: That is very unusual. Can you tried on different device to confirm? And could you create a simple repo on GitHub so I can try the exact same code you are having problems with?

Comment: Prerequisite:Window 10 OS verion 1809 or above
Sdk Version :Windows 10 SDK, version 1903.

can u create a simple uwp application with a button.On the button click paste the below following code:    

 var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
       dataPackage.SetText(" 1234");
       Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it this way. Can you try on a different PC?